# Reset Angular form with KendoUI events

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, kendo-ui

I am fairly new to AngularJS and need some help with refreshing an Angular form when an event happens. I’m using Kendo UI window modal to open the form and when the form is closed, I want to reset the form ($setPristine and empty form data) so it will be a fresh form when it’s opened again.

The window has a close event, so one solution that comes to mind is calling a controller function when the window is closed. But I’m having hard time implementing that when the event is triggered.

Below is the method that opens the modal window with the form and there is a dynamic button that calls it.

```
//open the modal with form 
function openModal(id){
    curItemId = id;
    console.log(curItemId);
    $("#window").kendoWindow({
        width: "800px",
        height: "510px",
        close: closedFunction, //can call a function from controller here?
        title: "",
        actions: [
            "Minimize",
            "Maximize",
            "Close"
        ]
    });

    var modalWindow = $("#window").data("kendoWindow");
    modalWindow.title("Contact Form");
    modalWindow.open();
    modalWindow.center();
}

<!-- this button is dynamically build and calls the above method -->    
<button id='"+e.Id+"' class='btn btn-default' onClick='openModal("+e.Id+")'>Contact</button>
```

Below is my controller, form calls the `submit()` function on submit but need to figure out a way to call the `clearForm()`method when window is closed?

```
var app = angular.module("contactApp",[]);
app.controller('ContactController', function($scope,$sce){
     console.log('controller initiated');

        //variables 
        $scope.formData = {}; //formData is an object holding the name, email, subject, and message

        //submit function
        $scope.submit = function(contactform,event) {
            if (contactform.$valid) {
                //submit data

            } else {
                //something is wrong, try again.
            }
        }

        //reset function
        $scope.clearForm = function(contactform,event){
            //reset the form
        }

});
```

I tried to move the `openModal()` method inside the controller and call it with `ng-click` from the dynamic button but was not successful with this as the `ng-click` was not working. Hope I made the issue clear, please do let me know if I can provide further details.

Thank you!